# WS_CLIPSIBLINGS style automatically added

Tags: windows, winapi

I created window with this window styles:
 **WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE**.

But for unknown reason **WS_CLIPSIBLINGS** style is automatically added.

Do you somebody know reason for this?

Sample code:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowExW(0, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: Top-level windows are always clipped wrt to each other. It's only child windows where the clipping is optional.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Thanks. Do you know some documentation, where is this explicitly mentioned?

Comment: No, although the docs are explicit about [child window clipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#clipping) and you can usually assume that if something explicitly mentioned for one thing it doesn't apply to other things that it's not explicitly mentioned for.

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it, you don't want other buggy applications accidentally drawing on your window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only child windows are mentioned in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles).

> Clips child windows relative to each other; that is, when a particular
>   child window receives a WM_PAINT message, the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS style
>   clips all other overlapping child windows out of the region of the
>   child window to be updated. If WS_CLIPSIBLINGS is not specified and
>   child windows overlap, it is possible, when drawing within the client
>   area of a child window, to draw within the client area of a
>   neighboring child window.

**Actually, All overlapped and popup-style windows have `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` properties. That is to say, you can't get rid of `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` attributes and draw in its overlapping brothers'windows.**

If it's just a child window, you can add `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` yourself.

[image: 1]

*Add WS_CLIPSIBLINGS*

[image: 2]

*After redrawing*