# Draw button on top of ImageList videos in C++ with winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having trouble drawing a button on top of a video with WinAPI. I am grabbing frames from the webcam and drawing those frames as soon as I get them. The problem is that whenever I draw an image the button disappears under it.

I tried using `SetWindowPos(button, HWND_TOPMOST, 50, 50, 50, 50, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);` to place the button at the topmost of the z-order but it still doesn't work.

The image is drawn on top of the button and this is a required behavior. I want the image to be as big as possible (taking the whole monitor).

I thought maybe I should make a part of the image transparent (the part over the button). Is that an easy solution and how should I go about doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [WS_CLIPSIBLINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) style to the button ,

> Clips child windows relative to each other; that is, when a particular
> child window receives a WM_PAINT message, the WS_CLIPSIBLINGS style
> clips all other overlapping child windows out of the region of the
> child window to be updated. If WS_CLIPSIBLINGS is not specified and
> child windows overlap, it is possible, when drawing within the client
> area of a child window, to draw within the client area of a
> neighboring child window.

Refer this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56470706/11128312

Comment: Hello, Thank you I had to use WS_CLIPCHILDREN on the main window for it to work.